# ChekBox checked always returns false

Tags: jquery

I have a `CheckBoxes` in a `GridView`, Now i want to check whether `CheckBox` is `checked` or not.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsReceived" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# Eval("IsReceived") %>' OnCheckedChanged="cbIsReceived_CheckedChanged" cssClass="cbIsReceived"/>
```

I am using the following Jquery to see the `CheckBox` state.

```
$('.cbIsReceived').live('click', function () {

        var result = $(this).is(':checked');
        alert(result);
    });
```

Which always alert false. even if i check it.

Please help.

Comment: try with `var result = $(this).prop('checked')` ? (btw live is deprecated)

Comment: i can see http://jsfiddle.net/eSmAU/ this is working fine

Comment: ya i test it on jsfiddle. its working finr . BUT its now working on my page. I dont know what, I have tried AutoPostback false also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#<%= cbIsReceived.ClientID%>').on('click', function () {
    var result = $(this).is(':checked');
    alert(result);
});
```

or

```
$('.cbIsReceived').on('click', function () {
    var result = $(this).is(':checked');
    alert(result);
});
```

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) intsead of deprecated [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop` function of `jquery` http://api.jquery.com/prop/

`$(this).prop('checked');`

Also `live` not works in latest version of `jquery 1.9` `http://api.jquery.com/live/`

Answer (score 0):

Use 'change' instead of 'click'.

```
$('.cbIsReceived').live('change', function () {

    var result = $(this).is(':checked');
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('.cbIsReceived').live('click', function () {
    if((this).is(':checked')){
        alert(result);
    }  
});
```

Comment: what if multiple checkiboxes with class .cbIsReceived ? edit: ok like this.